# JQuery Autocomplete Minimum Length For Multiple Words

Tags: jquery

I have this snippet code from [JQuery](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple)

I have changed it to `minLength: 3`, but it only applies to the first word. How do I configure it so that every word needs a minimum length 3?

```js
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    function split( val ) {
      return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
      return split( term ).pop();
    }
 
    $( "#tags" )
      // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
      .on( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      })
      .autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        source: function( request, response ) {
          // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
          let lastWord = extractLast(request.term);
          if (lastWord.length < 3) return;
          response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
            availableTags, lastWord ) );
        },
        focus: function() {
          // prevent value inserted on focus
          return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          var terms = split( this.value );
          // remove the current input
          terms.pop();
          // add the selected item
          terms.push( ui.item.value );
          // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
          terms.push( "" );
          this.value = terms.join( ", " );
          return false;
        }
      });
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tag programming languages: </label>
  <input id="tags" size="50">
</div>
```

I have added `if (lastWord.length < 3) return;`. It works but when I click back button (when I have 3 letters), it doesn't trigger it to hide the result.